# With PHP how do I extract a alpha numeric from a string

Tags: php, wildcard

I've been searching this for awhile but I could not find the exact same case with mine.

With PHP I need to extract a 2 group of numbers separated with a period within a series of number and characters, it's always in between the last "-" and the last period.

Like: exten-651-652-20140423-154650-**1398293210.14**.wav to this 1398293210.14

Hope anyone can share their thoughts on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MarkBaker missing parenthesis for the pattern?

Comment: fixed regexp `/(\d+\.\d+)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's always in between the last "-" and the last period.

```
$string = 'exten-651-652-20140423-154650-1398293210.14.wav';

$data = explode("-", $string);
echo str_replace('.wav', '', array_pop($data));
```

demo: https://eval.in/174006

Comment: I think he doesn't want the `.wav` at end of string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a filename, so:

```
$basefile = pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$parts = explode('-', $basefile);
$desired_part = end($parts);
```